# I can only see one filter at a time in photoshop

Tags: photoshop, filters

I am trying to reduce noise in an image by using the "reduce noise" filter + "surface blur", but i can only see one result at a time. I've tried using smart objects and also grouping the layers.

no matter what i do only the top layer is displayed.

thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Both of those filters directly alter the image they're applied to. If you apply them sequentially to an image, each will, in turn, replace the image with the result of the filter. If you apply the filters to individual copies of the image on separate layers, and those layers are in "Normal" blend mode with 100% opacity, you will only see the layer at the top of the stack. In order to get a different result, you will need to change either the blend mode, or the opacity, or both.